# How to embed special character in XML and have XDocument parse it

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

How to embed special character in XML and have XDocument parse it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
<Customer>
<CustomerID>BLAUS</CustomerID>
<CompanyName>Blauer See Delikatessen</CompanyName>
<ContactName>Hanna Moos</ContactName>
<Region>testing</Region>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<CustomerID>SPLIR</CustomerID>
<CompanyName>Split Rail Beer &#x25BA Ale</CompanyName>
<ContactName>Art raunschweiger</ContactName>
<Region>WY</Region>
</Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: That's not valid XML. The `&#x25BA` should probably be `&#x25BA;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you posted is not valid XML which is why it will fail to parse.

The problem is in this line:

```
<CompanyName>Split Rail Beer &#x25BA Ale</CompanyName>
```

Which should be:

```
<CompanyName>Split Rail Beer &#x25BA; Ale</CompanyName>
```

A properly encoded numeric entity is `&#x25BA;` (note the trailing `;`) - this translates to the character ►.